# The imported project "\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.3.1\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found

Tags: c#

After upgrading Microsoft.Net.Compilers from 3.1.1 to 3.3.1 in VS 2019, project build fails with:

```
The imported project "...\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.3.1\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Sure enough, there is no "tools" folder at packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.3.1\

I have tried deleting the packages folder and restoring Nuget packages as suggested by similar questions but the folder is still not there.

Comment: Please create a brand new project and add the 3.3.1 version. That new project should teach you how 3.3.1 uses a different approach to replace the compiler, without importing the targets file. Yes, it is a breaking change so you have to manually edit your project file to adapt to.

Comment: @LexLi The new project worked thanks. Just adding the 3.3.1 version there was enough to make it work for the current project.